# Some sonatype nexus questions

Tags: maven-2, maven, m2eclipse, nexus, sonatype

I deployed a sonatype nexus server inside my LAN , mapping some remote repositories to my public repositories :

[alt text http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/5517/7875d01884ad4234a5b02e2.png](http://img576.imageshack.us/img576/5517/7875d01884ad4234a5b02e2.png)

First question is , why these repositories not sync with the "real" repositories ?
For example , I mapped maven central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2) to "central" , but when I browse http://smallufo:8081/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/springframework/ , the packages are not complete , in http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/ , there are tons of artifacts , but I only have some of them :

[alt text http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6163/31beec445d6b4e9eb96beba.png](http://img63.imageshack.us/img63/6163/31beec445d6b4e9eb96beba.png)

And versions are old ...
ex : spring-core is only 2.5.6.SEC01 , but the latest version is 3.0.2.RELEASE.
And my maven client seems can only find the old artifacts ...
[alt text http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3872/maven.gif](http://img199.imageshack.us/img199/3872/maven.gif)

"central" is a proxy directory , it should be the same with the remote server. I tried to "Expire Cache" , "ReIndex" , "Incremental ReIndex" the whole "central" :
[alt text http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/8467/391bd49409c94aa58640afe.png](http://img23.imageshack.us/img23/8467/391bd49409c94aa58640afe.png)

After a long time with almost 100% java process load , the situation seems not better , just add some artifacts ... not reflecting the real "Maven Central" data...

Second question , what's difference with "Expire Cache" , "ReIndex" , "Incremental ReIndex" ?

Even I can "search" spring-core.3.0.2.RELEASE , my m2eclipse still cannot find it :
[alt text http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/9360/18c15abab4f343b0848a819.png](http://img217.imageshack.us/img217/9360/18c15abab4f343b0848a819.png)

I can also see the spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE in the "index" , (but not available in "storage") :
[alt text http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7041/maven2.gif](http://img268.imageshack.us/img268/7041/maven2.gif)

But why m2eclipse cannot make use of it ? it seems m2eclipse can only install artifacts in the storage , if this is how nexus works , how do I "force" download spring-core-3.0.2.RELEASE to nexus's storage ?

How do I solve these strange incompatibilities ?
Thanks a lot !

-- updated --

It seems it is problem with m2eclipse and maven-3.0-beta1.

After I change back to maven 2.2.1 , everything works fine now.

Sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nexus only caches artifacts that clients have requested. So you need to set up your project poms to request the proper versions.

Comment: It seems it is problem with m2eclipse and maven-3.0-beta1.
After I change back to maven 2.2.1 , everything works fine now.
Sorry for the disturbance.

Answer (score 1):

Nexus only proxies what the build has requested, that's why it doesn't have a full copy in the local storage of every repo. Trust me you wouldn't want that anyway. You typcially only need a very small subset of for example the 100gb Central repo.

You can read the details about the various Expire/Reindex etc operations here: [Nexus Scheduled Tasks](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/09/nexus-scheduled-tasks/)