# How to force Sonatype Nexus to update?

Tags: maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to use onejar-maven-plugin in my pom.xml:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.dstovall</groupId>
    <artifactId>onejar-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.exmaple.myproj.MpPort_MpSoapPort_Client</mainClass>
                <onejarVersion>0.97</onejarVersion>
                <attachToBuild>true</attachToBuild>
                <classifier>onejar</classifier>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>one-jar</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com</id>
        <url>http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
```

but for some reason, attempting to build it via the Eclipse Maven plugin (Maven install) results in BUILD ERROR:

```
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com (http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo)
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4

from the specified remote repositories:
  Nexus (https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central)

 for project org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin
```

So I manually downloaded [onejar-maven-plugin.jar](http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=com/jolira/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.jar) and install it through the command line and I seem to be getting a similar error:

```
C:\Users\daniel\myproj>mvn install:install-file -Dfile=onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.jar -DgroupId=com.jolira -DartifactId=onejar-maven-plugin -Dversion=1.4.4 -Dpackaging=jar
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com (http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo)
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
Downloading: https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/org/dstovall/onejar-maven-plugin/1.4.4/onejar-maven-plugin-1.4.4.pom
[INFO] Unable to find resource 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4' in repository central (http://repo1.maven.org/maven2)
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] BUILD ERROR
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Error building POM (may not be this project's POM).


Project ID: org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin

Reason: POM 'org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin' not found in repository: Unable to download the artifact from any repository

  org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin:pom:1.4.4

from the specified remote repositories:
  Nexus (https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central)

 for project org.dstovall:onejar-maven-plugin
```

My understanding is that because we have a Nexus mirror which doesn't contain that particular artifact, things get confused.

So I tried following the instructions on [How to force Sonatype Nexus Regenerate / Reindex its Metadata](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/javawug/HLBdWgBYIyQ) but **the “Browse Index” tab has no such context menu!** on our Sonatype Nexus.

[image]

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2979518/1864054) that "Nexus only caches artifacts that clients have requested. So you need to set up your project poms to request the proper versions". But **that's exactly what I have been doing** -- without any change in the outcome.

How do I get out of this "chicken & egg" situation and get this onejar-maven-plugin ver. 1.4.4 into my Nexus mirror?

(Alternatively, how do I get it into my local .m2 cache?)

Comment: In my case there were no space left on Nexus machine.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can force Maven to update and request dependencies again even if the local repo contains metadata about artifacts not be available with -U

```
mvn clean install -U
```

should work.

Also you should change your `settings.xml` to point to the public group instead of just the central repo directly. More can be found [in the Nexus book](http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/admin.html#repository-group).

And you should note that the Central Repository does not have the `onejar` plugin you are trying to use. Check out the [search results](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Conejar-maven-plugin) and see how the `groupId` is `com.joilira` and not `org.dstovall`

Further more if you really want to use the `onejar` plugin from `org.dstovall` you should add the url http://onejar-maven-plugin.googlecode.com/svn/mavenrepo/ as a proxy repository to Nexus, add it to the public group and then use the public group in your `settings.xml`

Comment: I was about to also suggest temporarily commenting out the `<mirrors>` element in his `settings.xml` (as a workaround to at least get the package into his local `.m2` cache) but then noticed that you had an even more brilliant insight: His Nexus points at `com.jolira`, not `com.dstoval`. +1 for that!

Comment: Its the pom.xml file that has the wrong reference. Nothing to do with Nexus really..

Comment: But if you look at the screenshot he provided, his Nexus does point to a `nejar-maven-plugin`, only it's from `jolira`, not `dstoval`. Isn't this what's causing his maven install to fail?

Comment: No... his Maven settings causes the download to be attempted from central as you can see from the error messages mentioning https://mynexus.example.com/nexus/content/repositories/central/

Comment: The problem is his Maven setup having a pluginRepo in the pom that is ignored because he is using mirrorOf * in his settings and the central repo there.

Comment: Turns out both of you were right. Yes, my settings.xml points to central instead of public, but really the root cause of my problem was not noticing that the **groupId** is different.